# How to map @PathVariable to CustomObject

Tags: spring, rest

Here is the sample code of my Spring Controller

```
   @Controller
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class ChildController extends ParentController<InterfaceController> implements InterfaceController{

        @Override
        @RequestMapping(value = "/map/list/{name}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK)
        @ResponseBody   
        public List<Friends> getAllFriendsByName(
            @PathVariable("name") String name,
            @RequestParam(value="pageSize", required=false) String pageSize,
            @RequestParam(value="pageNumber", required=false) String pageNumber,            
            HttpServletRequest request) throws BasicException {

        //Some logic over here;

        return results;
        }

    @Override
        @RequestMapping(value = "/map/{id}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK)
        @ResponseBody   
        public List<Friends> getAllFriendsById(
            @PathVariable("id") String id,
            @RequestParam(value="pageSize", required=false) String pageSize,
            @RequestParam(value="pageNumber", required=false) String pageNumber,            
            HttpServletRequest request) throws BasicException {

        //Some logic over here;

        return results;
        }

    }
```

Is there a way that I can cast both path variables name and id to same CustomObject that might look something like this:

```
public class CustomObject {

private String name;
private String id;
//Omitted setters and getters
}
```

So that my Controller looks something like this in the end

```
@Controller
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class ChildController extends ParentController<InterfaceController> implements InterfaceController{

        @Override
        @RequestMapping(value = "/map/list/{name}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK)
        @ResponseBody   
        public List<Friends> getAllFriendsByName(
            @PathVariable("name") CustomObject name,
            @RequestParam(value="pageSize", required=false) String pageSize,
            @RequestParam(value="pageNumber", required=false) String pageNumber,            
            HttpServletRequest request) throws BasicException {

        //Some logic over here;

        return results;
        }

    @Override
        @RequestMapping(value = "/map/{id}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK)
        @ResponseBody   
        public List<Friends> getAllFriendsById(
            @PathVariable("id") CustomObject id,
            @RequestParam(value="pageSize", required=false) String pageSize,
            @RequestParam(value="pageNumber", required=false) String pageNumber,            
            HttpServletRequest request) throws BasicException {

        //Some logic over here;

        return results;
        }

    }
```

I know it neccesarily cannot be bound to an object like that but this imaginary controller is just for the understanding.

So basically what i get is a String in the path variable which I want to directly convert to Entity using setter or CustomObject class.

Hope I was able to explain well. I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do what you ask. Since you only have access to the bounded variable and not other parts of the URL.

---

Previous answer from when I misunderstood the question. Might still be useful for others:

You need to add a method annotated with `@InitBinder`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomEditorsControllerAdvice {
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinderAll(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(CustomObject.class, 
                                    new CustomObjectPropertyEditor());

    }
}
```

The `CustomObjectPropertyEditor` is a class that extends from `PropertyEditorSupport` where you implement the `setAsText` method:

```
public class CustomObjectPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

  @Override
  public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      setValue(convertTextToMyCustomObject(text)));
  }

  private CustomObject convertTextToMyCustomObject(String text) {
      // TODO implement conversion here
  }
}
```

Note that I used a separate class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`, but you can add the `initBinderAll` method directly in the `@Controller` class as well if you want.

Comment: how would property editor know which variable to set, id or name

Comment: sorry, seems I misunderstood the question. But you cannot map the same url 2 times. Even the first code with the String parameter will not work. How could Spring make any distinction? It is just not possible.

Comment: My bad, I have actually one more differentiation in the URL, updated the question.